# Github isn't displaying my embedded images in my Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, embed

I uploaded a Jupyter notebook to GitHub with some screenshots that I embedded into markdown cells using the following format:

```
![Step1](Images/Step1.png)
```

However, when trying to view the notebook on GitHub, none of the embedded images appear. Is there something I can do to mend this?

[image]

I do not want users to have to run a Python code block to display the image. They are screenshots of different steps in a "getting started" guide I made, so I want them to appear in Markdown cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are posted on Github, open the image in a new tab, and copy the URL like so (Put in the actual link; I just added ellipses to redact the repository name):

```
![Step1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ ... /main/images/Step1.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but does your relative filepath need to point to the root directory? Like this:

```
![Step1](./Images/Step1.png)
```

That's my best guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not do the trick :( @MatthewEilar